# How to estimate an auto-regressive model?

Tags: estimation, autoregressive-model

Given a periodic impulse train and it's impulse response, how is an auto-regressive model of this system computed or estimated?

Comment: You know the drill. What have you Googled?

Comment: I am confused beacuse autoregression is a characteristic of a process, but it looks like you want to characterize a system (function that acts on a process).